# How do I use Nodejs for backend using SQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, node.js, backend, web-development-server

I am a beginner and this is my first full-stack web development project and I have completed the front-end part and created the related tables using MySQL... and now I want to link the tables to front-end using nodejs. How do I proceed further?? Is it proper to use workbench in the first place for a full-stack project?? Please guide me.

Comment: What is "*workbench*"? Are you perchance referring to [this abandoned NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbench)?

Comment: @esqew I am referring to the sql workbench

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Workbench is just an IDE for mySQL so thats fine for building out your DB, setting permissions etc.

Your question is not one that is simple to answer, simply because the steps in creating, setting up a full web app is not that simple to explain..

There are few things you will need to do to hook this up

1. Ensure you have a mySQL middleware installed
2. Ensure you have the routes created
3. Use a templating engine like EJS

Once you have the basic flow working ( meaning you can hit your page and it returns the correct page ) you will want to then hook into the DB before sending the response object back to the browser. A typical flow would be, on your 'get' response, you would perform the mysql 'select'

This should be promis based but will depend on the actual package you install, I don't use mysql but a postgres command is something like

```
query.pool("SELECT is, name, des from table where id = '10' ").then(results => {

//put in your response code here to send back to the page

}).catch( e => {console.error(e)})
```

The response code portion is where you would send things back to the page, in an ejs template would then be able to access the response and display the data.

I know, this is a bit light on full explanations and that is because the proper response would be huge!

Judging by the question I would guess you are a bit new to node / DB etc ( sorry if you are not ) I think what may be very helpful is to watch a few youtube videos on setting up Node and EJS ( or any templating engine for that matter )

That should give you the basic understanding and setup of the project.